# MOOC exercise sport statistics- how many times a string appears in a file?

Tags: java, string, file, count, contains

So I've been beating my head around this for a couple of days and I can't get it to work. I'm doing the exercise sports statistics in MOOC Java course.
I am supposed to check how many games the team (whose name the user inputs) has played.

In the data.csv file, there are a few lines, each one contains name 1, name 2, points 1, points 2.

So if the user enters for example "SJ", the program checks how many times is SJ mentioned in the file (ie. how many games this team played) and increments the count by 1 each time its mentioned.

I also tried to do this without creating a new class however, the result is still not the one I should get, as I can't seem to use the "for each" function, so I always get count = 1 if the team appears.

Is there somewhere a solution to this exercise?

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class SportStatistics {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("File: ");
        String file = scan.nextLine();
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get(file))){
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] parts = line.split(",");
                String team1 = parts[0];
                String team2 = parts[1];
                int result1 = Integer.valueOf(parts[2]);
                int result2 = Integer.valueOf(parts[3]);
                games.add(new Game(team1,team2,result1,result2));
            }
        }catch(Exception error){
            System.out.println("Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Team: ");
        String team = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

```
public class Game {
    private String team1;
    private String team2;
    private int points1;
    private int points2;
   
    public Game(String team1, String team2, int points1, int points2){
        this.team1=team1;
        this.team2=team2;
        this.points1=points1;
        this.points2=points2;
    }
   
    public String toString(){
        return this.team1 + ", " + this.team2 + ", "+ this.points1 + ", " + this.points2;
    }
}
```

```
ENCE,Vitality,9,16
ENCE,Vitality,16,12
ENCE,Vitality,9,16
ENCE,Heroic,10,16
SJ,ENCE,0,16
SJ,ENCE,3,16
FURIA,NRG,7,16
FURIA,Prospects,16,1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got you right.

Try reading the file after the user enters the team name.
When the user enters "SJ" then you read the file.
By getting the team names per line, check if team1 or team1 equals the user input "SJ" and increment the count variable.

If you want to use a for each loop, you go with something like:

```
for (Game g : games) {
    if (g.team1.equals("SJ") || g.team2.equals("SJ")) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

When you go the first way, you have to read the .csv file every time you want to count a team.

When you go the second way, it's enough to read the .csv once. Thus you have the data stored and you can ask for the team name in a while loop and call the method to go through the ArrayList games

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int games = 0;
    int wins = 0;
    System.out.println("File: ");
    String file = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Team: ");
    String team = scan.nextLine();
    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get(file))){
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(",");
            String team1 = parts[0];
            String team2 = parts[1];
            String winner = "";
            int result1 = Integer.valueOf(parts[2]);
            int result2 = Integer.valueOf(parts[3]);
            if (team1.equals(team) || team2.equals(team)) {
                games++;
                if (result1 > result2 ) {
                     winner = team1;
                } else {
                    winner = team2;
                }
                if (winner.equals(team)) {
                    wins++;
                }
            }
            
        }
    }catch(Exception error){
        System.out.println("Error " + error.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Games: "+games);
    System.out.println("Wins: "+wins);
    System.out.println("Losses: "+(games - wins));
}
```

Comment: Please add some descriptions to your code